# How to establish cross domain connection between website and server

Tags: reactjs, express, server, socket.io, cors

I see all over `stackoverflow` this is a common question I have tried many answers here but all of them didn't work, I'm using React as a front end, NodeJs express Socket.io as a backend, the React web app, and the server works fine on localhost no errors, but when I build React web app using `npm run build` and uploaded to the server, and upload the   express server files to the real server this error happened

`Failed to load resource: Origin https://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 404`

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OTswyEf due to access control checks. https://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OTswyEf`

In App.js

```
const socket = io('http://server.example.com',{
            auth:{token: token}},
            { transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] })
    
socket.emit('adminValues')
socket.on('adminValuesdata', (data)=>{
                    
     setData(data.list)

    })
  }
```

this is the server side and I have tried to edit cors origin many times and I didn't get lucky and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

```
const express = require("express")
const http = require('http')
const {Server} = require('socket.io')
const port = process.env.Port || 3001

const app = express()

const cors = require("cors")
const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        allowedHeaders: ['X-ACCESS_TOKEN', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'x-requested-with', 'Content-Type', 'Content-Range', 'Content-Disposition', 'Content-Description'],
        origin: 'http://www.example.com',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    },
})

server.listen('https://server.example.com', ()=>{
    console.log("Listen")
})
```

I have tried to set cors `origin: *` but also didn't work, HTTP and HTTPS, the server looks like this when I open it [image]

the last thing that I did was reading the real domain website from localhost server through HTTP and it did worked but https didn't and I sound tricky I edit the clint app socket.io to be like this

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3009',{ transports : ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'] },{
    auth:{token: token}}, {path: '/api/'})
```

and the local server to be like this

```
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://www.example.com",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
})
```

so when I read from the real server

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 404` ***was gone***

but I got another error

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: There was a bad response from the server`

in Firefox browser

`GET wss://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

`Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket.`

***The HTTP 404 Not Found response status code indicates that the server cannot find the requested resource. Links that lead to a 404 page are often called broken or dead links and can be subject to***
[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

this is the first time I'm working with a server I developed so is it normal that it should look like a text page maybe I need to install node on the hosting server

cause when I read the website `www.example.com` through HTTP and not HTTPS from the local server it worked, vise versa if I read the real server from my localhost website it will show the same errors as above

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://server.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: There was a bad response from the server`

what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Did you miss it in your original code or is it just in this post that you aren't calling `app.use(cors())`?

Comment: sorry but I did try this and I saw some answers referring to using cors only inside socket.io that's why I wrote the code like this I did try many things

Comment: I noticed you are using host URL as your first parameter to your `server.listen` whereas the first parameter to [`.listen` should be `...(port, hostname,...)`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_server_listen.asp)

Comment: Another issue or typo (?) is a wrong protocol in the `origin` property `http` instead of `https` if that's where your frontend runs

Comment: i have tried HTTPS and HTTP I will edit my question

Comment: do you mean I should do it like this `server.listen(3009, "http://www.server.example.com")` ?

Comment: Yes but if you have your backend deployed somewhere, you would need to pass `PORT` variable of value `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3009`

Comment: As for the protocol it can't be hit or miss, you either have security or not, if it's on localhost that's `http` if it's deployed somewhere like Netlify it's already `https` by them.